# Generate xml report for android Test task

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

I am running `./gradlew DebugUnitTest` task after completion its generating HTML report . is any way where I can generate XML report instead of HTML

Answer (score 2):

They are already there. The HTML reports are located in `app/build/reports/tests/`, while the XML reports are in `app/build/test-results`

Comment: XML doesn't give overall summary it shows class by class

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to write your own custom reporter then

Answer (score 0):

To activate xml test reports I had to add

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    reports {
        junitXml.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

to my gradle kotlin file. But they come in single xml files per test class.